# Bootstrap form inline

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

How can I perfectly align and space my inline inputs [forms](https://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/0ve7t8zo/) in bootstrap

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <input type="text" class= "form-control" value="First Name">
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <input type="text" class= "form-control"  value="Last Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use col-xs instead of col-lg 
 see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/scaisEdge/yqb7jkf8/1/) for a try

And keep all your  input inside the

```
 `<div class="form-group col-xs-12">`
```

Comment: Have you see the linked sample?

Comment: Yeah, the spacing is inconsistent with other inputs. it should stretch 100%

Comment: You need to do the same with all the input field. You can't use different grid spacing. you must repeate the schema for all the field look at sample now i ahev change other 2 field

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand our question very well, maybe a picture to illustrate what you want to achieve would be helpful.

I have basically wrapped everything with a column-xs-12 so its perfectly aligned. Also included an example if you want to place two input forms on one line. I have made a plunk to help you out, hope it helps.

```
<div class="col-xs-12"> </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/lj866U6QlvbLKhF4jujI?p=preview